# Python Float becomes string I can't convert to float

Tags: python

I am at a complete loss here.

My code has become very lengthy so I will only post the key parts here.  If needed I will put more up.  I appreciate any help I can receive on this one.  This forum has been so great to me.

Some values I need to add together.  I have it working fine in the first two sections.  It works 100% as expected.  I have the exact same code then duplicated with the different array values and everything works until I try to add the numbers.  I get an error saying I can't use + on a float and string.  If I try to do a xxx=float(xx) it says it's unable to convert to a float.

The confusing part of this is I already have it as a float and divided it by 1000.  But this value is suddenly a string with no changes I can see and I can't make it a float.  Any help would be great.

This is the relevant code.  The first two blocks work perfect.  The second two block work until I try to add the two values in which case the varible TCIF is a string and unable to be made a float.  The final line  fails.  If I do a TCIF - float(TCIF) it says it can't convert.

example of error when I try to explicitly convert

```
"..-Metrics.py", line 143, in <module>
    TCIF = float (TCIF)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Code:

```
matches = TotIntranetPort80.findall(line)
for firestick in matches:
    # Find and set 80 Proxy variable
    TotIntranetArrayPort80 = line.split()
    TIntranetPort80 = TotIntranetArrayPort80[5]
    TIntranetPort801 = TotIntranetArrayPort80[6]
    TIntranetPort80 = float(TIntranetPort80)
    if TIntranetPort801 == "MB":
            TIntranetPort80 = TIntranetPort80 / 1000

matches = TotIntranetPort443.findall(line)
for firestick in matches:
    # Find and set 443 Proxy variable
    TotIntranetArrayPort443 = line.split()
    TIntranetPort443 = TotIntranetArrayPort443[5]
    TIntranetPort4431 = TotIntranetArrayPort443[6]
    TIntranetPort443 = float(TIntranetPort443)
    if TIntranetPort4431 == "MB":
            TIntranetPort443 = TIntranetPort443 / 1000
            #print(TIntranetPort443)
    TIntranet = TIntranetPort80 + TIntranetPort443
    TIntranet = round(TIntranet, 2)
    TIntranet = str(TIntranet)


matches = TotFileXferCIF.findall(line)
for firestick in matches:
    # Find and CIFS For File Transfers
    TCIFArray = line.split()
    TCIF = TCIFArray[6]
    TCIF1 = TCIFArray[7]
    TCIF = float(TCIF)
    if TCIF1 == "MB":
           TCIF = TCIF / 1000

matches = TotFileXferSMB.findall(line)
for firestick in matches:
    # Find SMB File Transfers
    TSMBArray = line.split()
    TSMB = TSMBArray[5]
    TSMB1 = TSMBArray[6]
    TSMB = float(TSMB)
    if TSMB1 == "MB":
            TSMB = TSMB / 1000
    **TFileTransfer = TCIF + TSMB**
```

Comment: did u mean `firestick.split()`?

Comment: Have you looked at `TCIFArray[6]`?!

Comment: TCIFArray[6] is a series of numbers one decimal measure in MB or GB.  I have verified this.  Indeed I pluck the ones out in MB and divide by 1000 so everything is in GB.  No problem with that math..

Comment: try to print TCIF out after division

Comment: No problems printing it out after division.  All numbers look fine. here is sample of output from TCIF and TCIFArray[6] 11.9
11.9
18.3
18.3
11.2
11.2
12.8
12.8

Comment: then i guess you have to make it global as mentioned before

Comment: What do you mean make it global?  And why does it work on the first two but not this? I am missing something subtle I think.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Based on the error message, it seems that the value is an empty or all-whitespace string.

Comment: I deleted that comment. Even though it's not global. TCIF will contain the last value it held from the previous FOR loop. It looks kind of dangerous IMO.

Comment: float([x]) will return 0.0 in the case of a null argument.

Comment: hahahah ohhh I am sure this is not the best way.  It's my first Python of any significance.  I've only been at Python a few weeks

Comment: So, you know TCIF is always going to contain the same value?

Comment: I have looked for any white space or text.  I see none.  How can I verify anything in a float is no good?  any commands?

Comment: TCIF contains a looping value.  After I finish with this section it reads in an end marker sets it all to 0 and starts parsing the next section.  Like 100K lines.  It works great except for that crazy TCIF varible.

Comment: Both for-loops have "line.split()" they'll both contain the same values..

What is line.. first comment is probably right. I think you want firestick.split()

Comment: firestick.split goes out of range.  I am using a regex findall method with the regex defining the pattern to look for in each line. I tried and it just doesn't work. I dunno.  One set works one doesn't.  I am going to just use different names and try that.  The debug just gives me null values I think I am lost.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to start from this.
If you want to see what the zip([...]) command does, run the example below.

```
matches1 = TotFileXferCIF.findall(line)  
matches2 = TotFileXferSMB.findall(line)  
matches = zip(matches1, matches2) #shuffle lists together  

for firestick1, firestick2 in matches:  
    #do your work here
```

zip example:

```
matches1 = range(10)
matches2 = range(10,18)
print(zip(matches1, matches2))
```

output:

```
[(0, 10), (1, 11), (2, 12), (3, 13), (4, 14), (5, 15), (6, 16), (7, 17)]
```

Comment: Ok will do.  Haven't done lists and tuples yet.  Ha!  Next chapters.  I will see what zip does and work on it for a while.

Comment: It shuffles lists together. It's nifty. Especially if you have parallel arrays... which it looks like you do.

Comment: >>> matches1 = range(10)
>>> matches2=range(10,18)
>>> print(zip(matches1, matches2))
<zip object at 0x02502CB0>
>>>   No idea what this did

Comment: I using python 3 not 2 in case it matters

Answer (score 0):

Basic debuggging:

```
try:
    TCIF = float(TCIF)
except ValueError:
    print(repr(TCIF))
```

This will show you exactly what is in `TCIF` at the point of failure, and you can back-track from there.

Comment: Yeah that sounds good.  I am getting syntac errors but can google the way to write it.  Doesn't like the except line

Comment: I get empty ticks.  a list of ''

Comment: If what you are seeing is `''` then `TCIF` is empty, and `float()` cannot convert an empty string.

Comment: I wondered if that was the case.  But if I just print (TCIF) the number flows.  I will bang on it some more